# How to search for all transactional methods in Spring that will not work with autoproxy?

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

I have an application that is using Spring AOP with AspcetJ, and I want to convert it so that it can be used with spring auto proxy. Which means that I need to go through the code base looking for calls to @Transactional methods that are calling other @Transactional Methods within the same class and thus not going through the proxy, as well as @Transactional methods that are on private methods.

What tool or technique can I use to automatically find all the usages of @Transactional that would work with ApsectJ but not with auto prox?

Comment: Autoproxy and AspectJ aren't mutually exclusive. Do you mean you want to switch from AspectJ to JDK dynamic proxies or CGLIB proxies?

Comment: I mean switch from aspectJ loadtime weaving to cglib autoproxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any tool that will find these out of the box.  So you will probably need to write your own; but it is not trivial.

You can write an annotation processor to process methods/fields/classes with annotations on them.  See [the APT docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/apt/index.html) for how to write one and run it.  (Note that in Java 6, apt is built into javac.)

However, finding out which methods call which other methods is quite difficult.  Since you're talking about methods in the same class, it's a bit easier.  You could use bytecode analysis for this (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205497/java-or-bytecode-ast-generators-available-so-that-i-can-run-a-couple-of-visito) for some relevant libraries): just parse out the `invokevirtual` and `invokeinterface` instructions in your class' methods, and see if they match the ones with `@Transactional` annotations on them.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you are using AspectJ already, so why not use AspectJ to find out about such control flows dynamically and log them? So you could get rid of AspectJ by using AspectJ as an analysis tool. ;-)